# What is the behavior of electrons in a highpass filter circuit and what is an equivalent closed loop circuit?

Tags: high-pass-filter

I am being explained that an highpass filter in a circuit looks like this:
[image: Highpass filter]

It is hard for me to understand how this circuit works. Vin is AC voltage. I'm wondering what is an equivalent closed loop circuit. I'm thinking that an equivalent closed loop circuit would be the following:
[image: Highpass filter loop]

Is is correct to say that the second circuit contains an highpass filter (the capacitor and the resistor) filtering the frequency for the load to receive only some frequencies?

Also, I'm wondering what is the behavior of electrons in such a circuit? I'm thinking that the electrons flow in one way then the other since it's AC. But with the capacitor I'm thinking that half the period will be blocked by the capacitor since it will charge up on the left side and then discharge when the AC will switch side. So electrons will flow in only one direction toward the load that is when the current will flow from the negative node to the positive node.

Also, what are good values for R and C. The book I'm reading (Art of electronics 3rd edition) states that

Vout/Vin ≈  R / (R + X) = ωRC / (1 + ωRC).

What is the meaning of that ratio? Why is it important and what does it mean for the value of R and C? I know that reactance decreases with higher frequency. How does it allow to filter higher frequencies here?

Also won't the current flow through the resistor of the highpass filter wasting some current that the load won't receive also dropping the current value for the load?

The circuits are made using KiCAD.

Comment: _an highpass filter in a circuit looks like this_ - More accurately, your depiction is _one possible implementation_ of a high-pass circuit; there are many others.

Comment: But is the second circuit an equivalent?

Comment: Yes, it's also a high-pass filter, but no, it's not equivalent. Your idea of "closed loop" is confused. The first drawing indicating Vout is valid enough and does not need a second load resistor to be analysed.

Comment: Also you should generally stop thinking about electron flow and start thinking about charge flow. They are not the same thing.

Comment: It seems just easier for me to visualize when the circuit is closed then when you have a voltage applied to a line and stating that electrons will flow there. I'm not really familiar with electronics so I'm trying to develop an intuition. And I wondered how you would include a  highpass filter in a complete real circuit (that must be closed).

Comment: How does the first circuit materialize once included in a real life circuit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118726/discussion-between-reinderien-and-user123).

Answer (score 3):

First note that, yes, electrons will move a little, but this is not something you should be caring about during typical circuit analysis. Instead you should be thinking about the movement of charge. If you do not understand this, it's crucial that you backtrack and study how current and charge carriers work.

You also need to understand how a basic voltage divider works in order to answer this:

> What is the meaning of that ratio?

That ratio is a simple voltage divider, where the bottom element is a resistance and the top element is a reactance (X). If you do not understand voltage dividers, again, it's time to backtrack and develop a solid understanding before proceeding to AC analysis.

The simplest, most intuitive way to understand this circuit is that "capacitors block DC current and pass AC current". Since the capacitor is in the path of the current to the output, it will only allow AC current. The resistor will shunt away some current. The size of the resistance compared to the capacitor's reactance will determine the frequency past which current will be blocked: the cutoff.

Do not introduce a resistive load until you understand the above. The resistive load will change the behaviour of the circuit, effectively reducing the total resistance and changing the cutoff frequency.

Answer (score 2):

> with the capacitor I'm thinking that half the period will be blocked by the capacitor since it will charge up on the left side and then discharge when the AC will switch side. So electrons will flow in only one direction toward the load that is when the current will flow from the negative node to the positive node.

This is why electron models do more harm than good. People may end up thinking of capacitors as electron buckets, which they are not. When electrons flow into a capacitor on one plate, they flow out of the capacitor on the other, in both charge and discharge cycles.

Charging through the capacitor is a flow of current: conventional current from left to right across the top, towards the load. Discharging the capacitor is *also* a flow of current: from right to left across the top, from the load.

Intuitively, with a low-frequency AC the capacitor fills up early on in the half-cycle and stops current flow. Then the flow is reversed and it can discharge, for a short period in the negative half-cycle.

With high-frequency AC, each half-cycle does not completely fill the capacitor, so the complete half-cycle can flow before it is charged, and the same for discharge (or charging with the opposite polarity).